# How to filter joined models in Django?

Tags: django, join, filter, django-queryset

I have the following models:

```
class Street(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class House(models.Model):
    street = models.ForeignKey(Street, models.PROTECT)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('street', 'number')

class Room(models.Model):
    house = models.ForeignKey(House, models.PROTECT)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('house', 'number')
```

I already know the ID of a `Street` and would like to get all the rooms of all the houses in that street. In SQL that is easy:

```
SELECT *
FROM room JOIN house ON house.id = room.house_id
WHERE house.street_id = xyz;
```

Now how do I do this in Django? I tried

```
Room.objects.select_related('house').filter(street=xyz)
```

But I get an exception saying I can't access this field:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'street' into field. Choices are: house, house_id, id, number
```

Because of the amounts of data I am facing, I would really like to be able to join and filter using a single query! When giving up one or the other, I would have to resort to either making multiple queries or filtering in Python, both of which are inherently inefficient. An alternative would be raw queries, I guess...

Comment: There's a whole section of the docs on [filtering across relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get access to related object's field with `__` syntax:

```
Room.objects.select_related('house').filter(house__street=xyz)
```

This can be done as much time as you need, to select rooms by street name you can do this:

```
Room.objects.select_related('house').filter(house__street__name=xyz)
```

Chech details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

Comment: Note, you don't need the `select_related` to make the filter work on a joined model.

Comment: Cool. I totally missed the most obvious part of the documentation. Even left outer joins work like a charm!

Comment: @DanielRoseman Does it actually matter whether or not I also put the relevant joins into `select_related`? Will it select unnecessary fields?

Comment: @purefanatic `slect_related` allows you to fetch related object's data with one query. If you don't need house's details you can remove select_related. In this case `filter(house__street=xyz)` will also work. But if you doo `room.house` later in your code it will hit DB ane more time. More details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related