# In Django, how to make a join query with matching conditions in addition to the foreign key?

Tags: python, django, entity-attribute-value

We have a hand-written SQL query for proof of concept and hope to implement the function with the Django framework.

Specifically, Django's QuerySet usually implements a join query by matching the foreign key with the primary key of the referred table. However, in the sample SQL below, we need additional matching conditions besides the foreign key, like the `eav_phone.attribute_id = 122` in the example snippet below.

```
...
  left outer join eav_value as eav_postalcode
    on t.id = eav_postalcode.entity_id and eav_phone.attribute_id = 122
...
```

**Questions:**

We wonder if there is a way to do it with Python, Django framework, or libraries.

We also wonder if other programming languages have any mature toolkits we can refer to as a design pattern. So we highly appreciate any hints and suggestions.

**Backgrounds and Technical Details:**

The scenario is a report that consists of transactions with customized columns by [Django-EAV](https://pypi.org/project/eav-django/1.4.7/). This library implements the `eav_value` table consisting of columns of different data types, e.g. `value_text`, `value_date`, `value_float`, etc.

We forked an internal repository of Django-EAV and upgraded it to Python 3, so we can use any up-to-date Python features, although we are not using Django-EAV2. As far as we know, the new version, EAV2, follows the same database schema design.

So, the application defines a product with attributes in specific data types, and we referred it as **metadata** in this question, e.g.:

| attribute_id | slug | datatype |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 122 | postalcode | text |
| 123 | phone | text |
| ... | ... | e.g. date, float, etc. ... |

One transaction is one entity, and the `eav_value` table contains multiple records with the matching `entity_id` corresponding to the different customized attributes. And we want to build a dynamic QuerySet according to the **metadata** to assemble the customized columns with `left outer join` similar to the sample SQL query below.

```
select 
    t.id, t.create_ts
  , eav_postalcode.value_text as postalcode
  , eav_phone.value_text as phone
from
  (
    select * from transactions
    where product_id = __PRODUCT_ID__
  ) as t
  left outer join eav_value as eav_postalcode
    on t.id = eav_postalcode.entity_id and eav_phone.attribute_id = 122
  left outer join eav_value as eav_phone
    on t.id = eav_phone.entity_id and eav_phone.attribute_id = 123
;
```

Comment: Not sure how you'd do that within Django's ORM. If there's no other option, you could always use a [raw query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/sql/).

Comment: Maybe you could use [FilteredRelation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48180819/530160).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter joined models in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48685555/how-to-filter-joined-models-in-django)

Comment: @NickODell 's suggestion about `FilterRelation()` is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

We followed **@NickODell**'s hint on `FilteredRelation`, and our tentative solution looks like the below snippet:

```py
transaction_eav = transaction.annotate(
  eav_postalcode=FilteredRelation('eav_values', condition=Q(eav_values__attribute_id=22))
)

transaction_eav = transaction_eav.annotate(
    value_postalcode=F('eav_postalcode__value_text)}
)
```

We are new to Django ORM so please point out if the sample code above contains any low-efficient or non-standard flaws.

Many thanks to all for the great suggestions!

Comment: Glad to see that helped - one suggestion I'd make for seeing how well an ORM statement translates to SQL is to use `print(transaction_eav.query)` to show what SQL it is using to fetch your results. Also [Django Debug Toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is incredibly useful for debugging SQL performance issues.