# How to implement `left outer join` with additional matching condition, with `annotate()` or something else?

Tags: python, django, entity-attribute-value

The `transaction` (entity) records have customized attributes in EAV format, so we are implementing a design pattern that assembles EAV data with the entities by a series of `left outer join` operations in SQL query, briefly as the following:

- First, we have retrieved the metadata, e.g. `postalcode` corresponds to `attribute_id` of `22`, `phone` corresponds to `23`, etc.
- Then, we follow the metadata and construct a dynamic QuerySet by adding `annotate()` method calls.
- Like the below SQL query, the system behaviour is to repeat `left outer join` on the same `eav_value` table; however, besides the foreign key, the matching condition also requires a specific `attribute_id`. So, each join assembles one attribute.

**Our Question:**

We tried to assemble the first attribute appending an `annotate()` with `filter` to the existing QuerySet like:

```py
transaction.annotate(
  postalcode=F('eav_values__value_text'), 
  filter=Q(eav_values__attribute_id__exact=22)
)
```

The test got an error saying `AttributeError: 'WhereNode' object has no attribute 'select_format'`. And we believe the culprit is in the `filter` part because if we remove the argument, the error disappears.

So, how can we fix the issue and make the prototype run? And we are also OK to use something other than `annotate()` within the Django framework, not raw query.

We are new to this area of Django ORM, so we appreciate any hints and suggestions.

**Technical Details:**

**1. SQL query for assembling EAV data with entities:**

```sql
select t.`id`, t.`create_ts`
  , `eav_postalcode`.`value_text` as `postalcode`
  , `eav_phone`.`value_text` as `phone`
  -- , ... to assemble more attributes
from
    (
      -- entity: transaction, in a toy example of page size 2
      select * from `ebackendapp_transaction` where (`product_id` = __PRODUCT_ID__)
      order by `id` desc
      limit 2 offset 27000
    )  as t
    left outer join `eav_value` as `eav_postalcode` 
        on t.`id` = `eav_postalcode`.`entity_id` and `eav_postalcode`.`attribute_id` = 22
    left outer join `eav_value` as `eav_phone` 
        on t.`id` = `eav_phone`.`entity_id` and `eav_phone`.`attribute_id` = 23
    -- ... to assemble more attributes
;
```

**2. Test steps:**

```py
transaction = Transaction.active_objects.filter(product_id=__PRODUCT_ID__).order_by('-id').all()[27000:27002].values('id', 'create_ts')
print(transaction)
# OK

transaction_eav = transaction.annotate(postalcode=F('eav_values__value_text'), filter=Q(eav_values__attribute_id__exact=22))
# transaction_eav is OK, however:
print(transaction_eav)
# got an error saying "AttributeError: 'WhereNode' object has no attribute 'select_format'"
```

**3. Model definitions:**

```py
class Transaction(models. Model):
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    ...

# From the open-source Django EAV library
# imported as `eav_models`
# 
class Value(models. Model):
    '''
    Putting the **V** in *EAV*.
    ...
    '''
    ...
    entity_id = models.IntegerField()
    entity = GenericForeignKey(ct_field='entity_ct',
                                       fk_field='entity_id')

    value_text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    value_float = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    value_int = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    value_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    value_basicdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    value_bool = models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(Attribute, db_index=True,
                                  verbose_name=_(u"attribute"),
                                  on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Tentatively, we made a working prototype with [`FilteredRelation()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#filteredrelation-objects), see more in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74818556/7903749).

The document link targets Django v4.1 and we are currently on v3.1, though.